# How conditionally to colour a cell based on the most bottom repeated value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, conditional-formatting, countif

I have an Excel file that contains information like:

```
Invoice#,   Company Name, Amount
Invoice001, Company 001,  100.00
Invoice002, Company 002,  120.00
Invoice003, Company 003,  130.00
Invoice004, Company 001,  140.00
Invoice005, Company 158,  160.00
Invoice006, Company 003,   45.00
```

I want the cell background colour for the most recent repeated company invoice number (ie the highest numbered - but they are ordered in my spreadsheet top to bottom) to have a green background.

In my example, the cells with the background green colour would be the cell with the company name for `Invoice004` (not `Invoice001` even though it is the same customer but it isn't the most recent invoice), `Invoice002`, `Invoice006` (not `Invoice003` - same reason as `Invoice004`) and `Invoice005`.

Ideally I just want to do this with a formula in the cell to change the background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=OR(COUNTIF(B$2:B$10,B2)=1,COUNTIF(B3:B$10,B2)=0)
```

to be applied as a conditional formatting formula starting from A2 with B$10 adjusted as necessary.

On reflection, the first COUNTIF isn't necessary: just that there are no more recent invoices for the same customer, assuming that the invoices are in chronological order:-

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B$10,B2)=0
```